# Nautilus strange 'shift' key behaviour when renaming files

Tags: nautilus

There is a really puzzling behaviour in Nautilus regarding my <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
Consider the following scenario:

1. I click on any folder in `/home` and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename it.
2. During *renaming* I can type just fine *unless* I need a capital letter. If I type a capital letter (using shift, for ex. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to get a capital M) then focus shifts to the first folder in `/home` that starts with `M`. Moreover the folder that accepts the focus is in edit mode (!!)

I could not reproduce this in my other Ubuntu PC, so it has to be something with nautilus settings in this specific PC.
Can somebody explain this strange behaviour?

(I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. The problem was still existent in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version.)

Comment: Weird indeed. Does the same happen with a freshly created user profile (e. g. in a temporary guest session)? Make sure, that the Nautilus installation isn't corrupted or outdated by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus/vivid && killall nautilus && nautilus`. If the issue persists, you should [file a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it does not happen with a freshly created user profile! reinstalling nautilus did not help though...

Comment: With Ubuntu 16.04 it happens only in "view items as a list" mode. The workaround from the comment 3 below doesn't work any more though :(

Comment: Found the solution! See my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit I had the similar behavior in "Files":

- You can rename files and folders in "View items as a grid of icons" mode
- In the "View items as a list" mode:

  - Pressing <kbd>right shift</kbd> while renaming is similar to pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>
  - Pressing <kbd>left shift</kbd> works
  - Pressing <kbd>left shift</kbd>+<kbd>any letter</kbd> is similar to pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>left shift</kbd>+<kbd>any letter</kbd>

As a result it's not possible to enter any capital letters in the "View items as a list" while renaming a file or a folder.

**The solution:**

- Go to `System settings`/`Keyboard`
- Switch to the `Shortcuts` tab
- Select `Universal access` on the left hand side
- Remove zoom bindings

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is a very annoying bug. 
Following this suggestion

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nemo/+bug/1409353/comments/3

disabling the input source switch shortcut/accelerator worked for me. This, without having to restart nautilus to see the impact.

In fact using "Shift+Shift R" makes the strange behavior happen.
But using another choice like "Alt+Escape" and "Alt+Ctrl+Escape", makes the renaming features work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus is showing a bug involving renaming files and iBus, [at least since 2014](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1385292). Now in 2017 the bug persists. I'm having similar problems in Debian+Gnome, when trying to rename files. I succeed in renaming the first 2 or 3 files, just to not being able to rename anything anymore. I press F2, the edit field appears, but the keyboard won't respond anymore.

Now, is this really a bug, or possibly some kind of industrial sabotage to avoid spread of free software, and the consequent change in the industry's philosophy, and also to hinder the development of other countries? (iBus is used to type languages different from English.) If you think I'm paranoid, then why such a ridiculous bug still persists after 3 years?